# $M(\theta)$ is a straight line

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to prove that $M(\theta)=\{$ $(t\cos\theta,t\sin\theta) \mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a straight line, through a theorem if curvature $\kappa(s) = 0$ for all $s$  iff the curve is a straight line.

Is it okay to use this theorem? Would my 's' there be my 't' true or not? Or is there another way to prove that? thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it easier just to prove this is a line through the origin making angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis?

Comment: How did you define "straight line"? Given that you have an expression of the form $\{t\cdot v: t\in\mathbb R\}$ for a non-zero vector $v$, I wouldn't be surprised if your definition just immediately says, "oh yeah, that's a line" and even if it doesn't (e.g. if it's the set of solutions to $ax+by=c$ for $a,b$ not both zero), I doubt that curvature is a expedient way of proving it.

Comment: Every straight line can be written that way and that shape always represents a straight line, a iff , so i believed with that of curvature it would already be demonstrated, with that expression a sense would already be resolved i think?